# Set up Python environment with Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have just installed VS Code additionally to my Anaconda Environment. 
I have installed the following extensions in VS Code:

- Python (Linting)
- Anaconda Extension Pack

I have selected the Python Interpreter I want to use:

- Ctrl + A+ P
- Type in ">Python: Select Interpreter"
- I have chosen "Python 3.6.10 64-bit ('py35': conda)"

About the Interpreter that I am using: When I first opened my Anaconda Navigator, I navigated to "Environments", clicked the "Create" button, typed in the name "py36" for my new environment, created an environment for Python 3.6. I have installed some additional packages such as keras already. This is the environment that I want to use. It is located in the following direcoty:

C:\Users\luk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36

I have not included any of my anaconda-directories to PATH.

When I run a simple test.py program in VS Code with just the following two lines:

```
msg = "Hello World"
print(msg)
```

The program runs just fine. However, when I run the following test.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)  # Create a list of evenly-spaced numbers over the range
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))       # Plot the sine of each x point
plt.show()                   # Display the plot
```

The following error message appears in my terminal:

```
conda activate base
conda: "conda" has not been recognized as name of a cmdlet, a function ...
```

It is probably related to my PATH settings. So, I have included the following directories to PATH:

C:\Users\luk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
C:\Users\luk\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts

Still no luck tho. Can anyone help?

Comment: allright. Actually, adding the two directories to PATH did solve my issue! Aditionally, I just had to type "conda init" in my powershell and then restart VS Code. Thank god!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't add conda to your PATH, you can do one of two things:

1. Set `"python.condaPath"` in your settings to point to `conda`
2. Launch VS Code from the Anaconda Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Using the Anaconda desktop app, you may follow these steps to use Anaconda within VS Code:

1. Under "Home", click the VS Code "Launch" button
2. Go to "File", then "Open" to open your Python code
3. Navigate to the "Run and Debug" tab on the left, then "Run and Debug" button